# Setting a transparent color in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, colors, transparency

Is it possible to set a transparent color for images loaded in HTML5?

I would be looking for something similar to the setColorKey() function available in SDL.  This would be used to easily remove a background from some sprite sheets that I will be using.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create the image with a transparent background in the first place?

Comment: That's definitely possible, but I was simply curious

Comment: Well the question I'd be asking myself is: why do this processing repeatedly, on every page load on every client instead of doing it just once on the server?

Comment: One reason to do this "on the fly" would be if you want to use different color palettes with sprites

Comment: @JaniHartikainen I'm not saying there isn't a good reason, I'm just saying make sure you have a good reason why you're not doing it server side or even offline.  And if you want to mess around with the entire colour palette of images dynamically then SVG is probably a better place to start.

Comment: Yeah I was just mentioning a use-case when you would want to do this :)

Comment: Like I said, moreso a curiousity if HTML5 had a facility for this.  My game programming was previously limited to SDL so my first thought was to set a transparent color as I had done in the past.  Like robertc said, I will probably just use a transparent color for my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no very straightforward way to do this, but you can use the `<canvas>` tag to do this.

Draw your image in the canvas, using `drawImage`, and then use `getImageData` and `putImageData` to perform pixel manipulation on it.

There are some examples of pixel manipulation in canvas here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes

Answer (score -1):

There is no built in function for this. If this doesn't need to be dynamic, then you could remove the color from the original image and make those areas transparent. Then you put the images in a div that has the background color that you just removed from the image. After that you change the background color of the div when you mouse over the image.

If that sound like the right idea and you need some starter code let me know.

Comment: That's not much use if you can't see the background through the image.

Comment: sorry about that. I just reread your question and I am editing my answer

Comment: The question is about replacing a single colour in an image with transparency, not making the entire image translucent.

Comment: I don't think that's possibly @David

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it isn't (unless the canvas API has something for it), but that is what the question is asking.